# CMake ignoring -DCMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY flag

Tags: cmake

I'm sorry if this is obvious, but I have a command that basically does the following:

`mkdir -p /home/developer/cmake-build-debug
cd /home/developer/cmake-build-debug
cmake -DCMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/home/developer/cmake-build-debug -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..`

I'm expecting this to build the CMake project in /home/developer and output the Makefile etc. to /home/developer/cmake-build-debug. However, the output I get is

`Output Directory: /home/developer/cmake-build-debug
-- Boost version 1.58.0
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/developer`

and the build artifacts get created in /home/developer.

The reason I get the first line is my CMakeLists.txt has the following line in it for debugging: `message("Output Directory: ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}")`.

This has happened before and I think it kind of "randomly" stopped happening, but I just rebuilt the docker container in which I'm doing this and I'm at a loss for why this is happening. Can someone explain why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: IIUC, you want the build files (like the generated `Makefile`) to be placed under the directory you specified with `-DCMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`? That's not what that flag is for. [`CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) sets the location for generated executables, basically, where any executable file created via `add_executable(...)` will be placed.

Comment: @Justin Oh, I see. Thank you! Is it possible to also place the build files somewhere else? I'm not seeing a `CMAKE_BUILD_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` or anything like that.

Comment: Usually what I do is navigate to the build directory and invoke cmake there: `cd /home/developer/cmake-build-debug`, `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug /path/with/cmakelists <other-args>`

Comment: @Justin I'm not sure what you mean. This is what I'm doing. However, the `Makefile` still gets generated in /home/developer

Comment: I'm seeing evidence that other people are doing the same thing. I'm confused as to why this isn't working for me. I'm literally typing `pwd && cmake ..` and it's saying `/home/developer/cmake-build-debug ... Build files have been written to: /home/developer`

Comment: I removed `/home/developer/CMakeCache.txt` and that seems to have worked, though I am very unclear why.

Comment: Make sure the project doesn't modify `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` or some other *read-only* variables.

Comment: @RiverTam Yes, that would do it. You don't want `/home/developer/CMakeCache.txt` or `/home/developer/CMakeFiles/`. That file and directory should be in the build directory, not in the source directory.